# how to run my selenium script on multiple servers at the same time so that i would saved one by one execution time?

Tags: selenium, automation, automated-tests

how to run my selenium script on multiple servers at the same time so that i would save one by one execution time ?
Scenario: I have 1 hour of total testing time and 20 servers to test and 1 test script takes about 30mins to execute so i want to run my test script simultaneously on all 20 servers in order to save time.

Comment: use Selenium Grid

Comment: You can use parallel execution using testng.xml. Provide more details in order to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is parallel execution
There are multiple ways to achieve this like 1> Creating a **Jenkins** Job, Registering all the server machines as slave and executing jobon servers
Or
2> A comparitively simpler and more widely used concept, using **Selenium Grid**
To Implement Selenium Grid ( for instance with java as a programming language and TestNG framework) we need to take care that 
**A.** we have implemented Threading for our webdriver, so that each execution works on its own driver instance.
**B.** We have our Testng.xml with attribute set as **parallel=tests**

You can easily get step by step guide to establish selenium grid to summarize it, We have one machine as hub(master), we have multiple machines or nodes(slave) registered to the hub, your automation code is supplied to the hub, Hub routes test on multiple nodes keeps track of individual execution and gets you the result on the Hub machine itself